# How to tell whether promise has error handler

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

Is it possible, within a `new Promise((resolve, reject) => { //here })` block to tell whether a promise has a catch handler (or error handler, more generally, as for `.then(..., errorHandler)` clauses)?

I'd like to print an error message in case the promise hasn't, but otherwise don't.

Comment: it can't possibly have one `here` because `here` is executed during the construction of the Promise, and a Promise can't have any `handlers` until it has been constructed ...

Comment: You will have no idea if the Promise is part of another Promise or if it has been chained.

Comment: @JaromandaX: Not all of `//here` might execute during the construction (e.g. any async callbacks inside `//here`), so it is conceivable the a callback inside the promise body could inspect the variable containing the promise itself. However, AFAIK, `Promise` API does not provide a way to inspect the attached handlers, so the point is moot.

Comment: indeed, and cgTag's point is a good one too - you definitely can't "inspect" down the chain

Comment: Your browser is quite good at printing error messages for unhandled promise rejection already. What is it you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: If your concern is always catching errors, if you can use async/await, that will help you to do just that. But it's not all that comparable, and rather new.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I doubted that this would have been possible, so thanks for clarifying. @Phil: error message for now (you're right, the browser can do that), but perhaps special exception handling. Would it be possible to have a default error handler instead (in case no other error handler is being executed), outside of the promise constructor?

Comment: could possibly use Promise.reject in this case? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to check in the promise scope, but you could add a listener for a un-handled rejection in the browser. A event will be emitted if there was a un-hanlded promise.

Browser

```
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', function(event) {
    // event.promise error handling 
});
```

Node

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', function(err, promise) {
    // promise error handling 
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/onunhandledrejection
https://thecodebarbarian.com/unhandled-promise-rejections-in-node.js.html